# Unity Multi-touch (Pinch) to Scale Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use multi-touch (Pinch) to scale the object.
It works fine but when I let go of the 2 touches and try to zoom-in & out again,
The object keep trying to go back to its original scale.

I used code below.

```
if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
    Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0); 
    Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

    Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
    Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

    float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
    float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

    float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;
    float pinchAmount = deltaMagnitudeDiff * 0.02f * Time.deltaTime;
    objectImRotating.transform.localScale += new Vector3(pinchAmount, pinchAmount, pinchAmount);
}
```

Comment: Btw what if not both touches where moved? ;) Another sidenote: You could write `new Vector3(pinchAmount, pinchAmount, pinchAmount)` as `Vector3.one * pinchAmount;`

Comment: @derHugo If both of them are not moved, the object stays still. and If one of them moved and another one didn't the object is scaling up and down according to the position of touch which moved.

Comment: But this would only happen if you had a `||` instead of a `&&` between them right?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah u're rite

Comment: @derHugo i uploaded a gif image of what's happening now. u will see after first scaling, if i try them again the object wants to go back to it's original scale.

Comment: Is it possible that Unity remembers where the touch was before so `touchZero.deltaPosition` is no exactly the invert of the before movement and thus it scales the object down again?

Comment: @derHugo hmm got no idea. but i'm gonna follow ur answer and test it out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the reason of the issue but here is what I would do: Rather not use a frame-wise addition for scaling but do something like

```
private Vector2 initialDistance;
private Vector3 initialScale;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        var touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0); 
        var touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // if one of the touches Ended or Canceled do nothing
        if(touchZero.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touchZero.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled  
           || touchOne.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touchOne.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) 
        {
            return;
        }

        // It is enough to check whether one of them began since we
        // already excluded the Ended and Canceled phase in the line before
        if(touchZero.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touchOne.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            // track the initial values
            initialDistance = Vector2.Distance(touchZero.position, touchOne.position);
            initialScale = objectImRotating.transform.localScale;
        }
        // else now is any other case where touchZero and/or touchOne are in one of the states
        // of Stationary or Moved
        else
        {
            // otherwise get the current distance
            var currentDistance = Vector2.Distance(touchZero.position, touchOne.position);

            // A little emergency brake ;)
            if(Mathf.Approximately(initialDistance, 0)) return;

            // get the scale factor of the current distance relative to the inital one
            var factor = currentDistance / initialDistance;

            // apply the scale
            // instead of a continuous addition rather always base the 
            // calculation on the initial and current value only
            objectImRotating.transform.localScale = initialScale * factor;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*